# Retrieve active key binding using a commandId

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am currently working on an Eclipse RCP plugin containing a set of tool bar buttons triggering actions, which can also be triggered by keyboard shortcuts.

Here is the relevant part of my *plugin.xml* file, with the context, the command and the corresponding key binding for the shortcut:

```
<plugin>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.contexts">
      <context id="notepad4e.context" name="In Notepad4e" parentId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window" />
   </extension>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <category id="notepad4e.command.category" name="Notepad4e" description="Category for Notepad4e commands" />
      <command categoryId="notepad4e.command.category" id="notepad4e.command.text.bold" description="Sets style to bold" name="Bold" />
   </extension>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key commandId="notepad4e.command.text.bold" contextId="notepad4e.context" sequence="CTRL+B" schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration" />
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

In my Java code, I am correctly activating the `notepad4e.context` for my view and activating a handler to listen to the corresponding keyboard event. The keyboard shortcuts seem to be working fine and the user can redefine the key binding in Eclipse's preferences to best suit his needs.

I would like to set a tool tip text to the tool bar button with information about the binding as follows:
[image: Button with tool tip text shortcut]

I cannot hardcode the key binding information, as the user might change the binding, and the hardcoded value would no longer be valid. I am trying to come up with a solution to programatically retrieve the key binding for a given command. I have the following three attempts ussing the [IBindingService](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fkeys%2FIBindingService.html) :

```
private String getShortcutDescription1() {
    IBindingService bindingService = getViewSite().getService(IBindingService.class);
    TriggerSequence triggerSequence = bindingService.getBestActiveBindingFor("notepad4e.command.text.bold");
    if (triggerSequence != null) {
        return triggerSequence.format();
    }
    return "";
}

private String getShortcutDescription2() {
    IBindingService bindingService = getViewSite().getService(IBindingService.class);
    TriggerSequence[] triggerSequences = bindingService.getActiveBindingsFor("notepad4e.command.text.bold");
    if (triggerSequences.length > 0) {
        return triggerSequences[0].format();
    }
    return "";
}

private String getShortcutDescription3() {
    IBindingService bindingService = getViewSite().getService(IBindingService.class);
    for (Binding binding : bindingService.getBindings()) {
        if (binding.getParameterizedCommand() != null
                && "notepad4e.command.text.bold".equals(binding.getParameterizedCommand().getId())) {
            return binding.getTriggerSequence().format();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

The two first solutions don't seem to find any binding associated with the `notepad4e.command.text.bold` commandId. Yet with the third solution, I do find the expected binding. Nevertheless, going through all of Eclipse's bindings doesn't seem like an efficient solution and more importantly if the user redefines the default shortcut in his preferences, the `bindingService.getBindings()` call returns a collection containing both the inactive default binding and the active redefined user one, so this won't either return the value I'm looking for.

What am I missing out here? How can I programatically retrieve the active key binding for a given commandId?

Thanks in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT 17/01:** the two first solutions do return the wanted binding, but they only seem to do so after the user has interacted with the plugin. This is not practical as I am trying to set the tool tips when the plugin is being set up.

Comment: You should be able to use `Binding::getContextId()` to find the right binding for your context.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann: if you are referring to the third method attempt, unfortunately, the two bindings returned by `bindingService.getBindings()` have the same contextID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I have opted for the following solution:

```
private String getShortcutDescription() {
    Binding bestBinding = null;
    for (Binding binding : getViewSite().getService(IBindingService.class).getBindings()) {
        if (binding.getParameterizedCommand() != null
                && "notepad4e.command.text.bold".equals(binding.getParameterizedCommand().getId())) {
            if (bestBinding == null) {
                bestBinding = binding;
            } else if (binding.getType() == Binding.USER) {
                // Give higher priority to a user type binding (user has overriden default).
                bestBinding = binding;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return bestBinding == null ? "" : " " + bestBinding.getTriggerSequence().format();
}
```

The correct binding is returned even if the user has not yet interacted with the plugin (context active but view not active). As stated in the question, if the user redefines the default shortcut in his preferences, the above `bindingService.getBindings()` call returns a collection containing both the inactive default binding and the active redefined user one. If found, I select the one with type `Binding.USER`. If the user has not redefined the binding, only one binding with type `Binding.SYSTEM` exists and is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Testing here it looks like you may be calling the `getBestActiveBindingFor` code too soon after activating the context.

Just changing your code to call `getShortcutDescription1` in a `Display.asyncExec` `Runnable` makes it work. So it looks like some setup needs to be completed before you can make this call.

For testing I used:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() ->
  {
    System.out.println("trigger " + getShortcutDescription1());
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this does not work for me. Nevertheless you seem right by pointing out a timing issue, I tried calling the function several seconds later by a user triggered action and it does work. I guess I could schedule some sort of task delayed by an arbitrary number of seconds to set the tool tips, but it does feel a bit clumsy.

Comment: After some extra testing, even introducing a delay doesn't work either. `getBestActiveBindingFor` only returns the binding if the user has previously clicked at least once in the plugin's view.

Comment: Well that sounds like the view is not active when you are calling this code - as the method name implies this is the best **active** binding. If your context is not active because some other view is active it won't find anything.